# Is there a mode/profile/permission that automatically rollbacks all requests submitted by a user?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

At work, we have production databases on which developers have read permission. When developers have to fix something in the database, they must test their scripts in a copy of the production databases and then ask the DBA team to execute it in production.

Sometimes however, the data that must be fixed is not in the test databases. Developers then ask for a new copy of production databases, and this can take a lot of time.

Of course, we could grant them update permission and ask them to use BEGIN TRANSACTION / ROLLBACK, but it is too risky. Nobody wants that, not even the developers.

**My question**: is it possible to create a profile on SQL Server - or grant special permission - that would allow to execute update and delete commands but would *always*, no matter what the developer wrote, rollback after a GO or after the last command issued in a session?

This would be really helpful to test scripts before sending them to production.

Comment: "Developers then ask for a new copy of production databases and this can take a lot of time" - but surely you must be restoring those somewhere frequently anyway?  Why is restoring a backup slow? It's possible to restore a 1TB database in 1-2 hrs. And no, there is built-in no way to do what you want.  You should fix the real problem....

Comment: @MitchWheat Thank for the suggestion. The reason why restoring a database can be slow is probably because we have offices all around the world, a lot of applications talking to each other (restoring the database for one application means restoring databases for all applications), a lot of developers, a lot of users, a lot of priorities, and a limited IT Department. Maybe we should hire more people, I don't know. However, the mode I'm talking about would have been the easiest solution to this problem.

Comment: "restoring the database for one application means restoring databases for all applications" - that's often a symptom of less than optimal design. That's like saying everything is connected; can't change one piece without everything else changing.

Comment: @MitchWheat Less than optimal of course: some of the components/applications are newly developed, other have been developed years ago, some have been bought and customized, some are using their own DBMS, and most of them are working together. The usual large enterprise...

Comment: The feature you're asking for runs into much of the same trouble as [`IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql) does: forgetting to end the transaction can lock up a lot of things, while immediately rolling back every statement would make multi-statement transactions fail. Even so, you could *consider* using `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`, as long as developers don't forget to close their sessions -- all open transactions are rolled back when a connection is closed. (But they will forget.)

Comment: To auto-set this for an account, you'd need a logon trigger, and a guardian angel to watch over you. Overall, it makes a lot more sense to look into a reliable staging environment. Often, it is not necessary to have *precise, exact copies of the whole database* -- if you can restore whole databases on a regular basis, and then selectively copy over critical data on demand (with some simple scripting, or replication, or SMO), you'll have something that's "good enough" to test the outcome of scripts of this kind. If you *have* to do it in production, there's no substitute for careful work.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you! I was hoping that such a feature would exist, but it's not a problem most of the time. It would just have eased the process. That said, as far as I remember, most of the (large) companies I worked with would have welcome used this features, I think. May be I should submit this idea to the SQL Server dev team...

Comment: You could always [throw it on the pile](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server), but with 8000+ ideas and plenty of workarounds for this scenario, I wouldn't hold my breath. :-)

Comment: If this is a problem that happens often enough that you need a standardized solution for it, your time might be more well spent building data validation into the front end, mitigating the need to do after the fact clean up.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the link.

Comment: Straightforward would be a trigger which rollbacks every transaction a user from certains user group makes

Comment: perhaps you may need to use differential Backups, which will be easier and faster in case if the `the data that must be fixed is not in the test databases`. However, you'll need also to scheduled a routine maintenance plan that force all developers and DBA to update the database with the latest fixes in a due date. And schedule the fixes as well to be inside that plan. This would make things much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a sproc and give EXEC access to devs on that sproc only, **SOLUTION #1 - SPROCS**. This is probably the most elegant solution as you want them to have a simple way to run their query and also want to control their perms on the production environment. Example to execute a command would be: `EXEC [dbo].[usp_rollback_query] 'master', 'INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2`

**SOLUTION #1**

```
USE [DATABASENAME]
GO

ALTER PROC dbo.usp_rollback_query
(
    @db VARCHAR(128),
    @query NVARCHAR(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @main_query NVARCHAR(max) = 'USE [' + @db + ']

    ' + @query;

    BEGIN TRAN
        EXEC sp_executesql @main_query;
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END
```

If you can afford to have snapshot created and dropped each time, **SOLUTION #2 - DB SNAPSHOTS** is the best way to go about it. It's super fast, the only two drawbacks are that you need to kick people off the DB before you can restore and it will restore all changes made since the snapshot was created.

**SOLUTION #2**

```
-- CREATE SNAPSHOT
CREATE DATABASE [DATABASENAME_SS1]
ON
    (
        NAME = DATABASENAME,
        FILENAME = 'your\path\DATABASENAME_SS1.ss'
    ) AS SNAPSHOT OF [DATABASENAME];
GO

-- let devs run whatever they want

-- CLOSE CONNECTIONS
USE [master];
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DATABASENAME]
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

-- RETORE DB
RESTORE DATABASE [DATABASENAME]
FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT = 'DATABASENAME_SS1';
GO

-- CLEANUP SNAPSHOT COPY
DROP DATABASE [DATABASENAME_SS1];
```

I don't think ROLLBACK on each query is a good idea or a good design but if you have to go that route, you would need to use triggers. The limitation with triggers is that a DATABASE or SERVER level trigger can only be for DDL and not DML. Creating triggers on each TABLE object that you think is being altered is doable, however, the drawback here is that you need to know which tables are being modified and even then it's quite messy. Regardless please look at **SOLUTION #3 - TABLE TRIGGERS** below. To make this better you could create a role and check if the user is part of that role, then rollback.

**SOLUTION #3**

```
USE DATABASENAME
GO

ALTER TRIGGER dbo.tr_rollback_devs
   ON  dbo.table_name
   AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF SYSTEM_USER IN ('dev1', 'dev2')
        ROLLBACK
END
GO
```